# Problem with navigation bar on Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I need help solving a problem. I want to make it so that the logo is on the left side of the top navigation bar, but every attempt to implement this breaks the frontend.

*The code itself:*

```css
.top-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
}

.top-line li {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <!-- CSS Bootstrap 4.5.2 -->

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">

          <!-- One of the primary actions on mobile is to call a business - This displays a phone button on mobile only -->
          <div class="navbar-toggler-right">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
              aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" id="navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end top-line w-100 px-3">
              <img class="logo" src="https://svgshare.com/i/hqG.svg" alt="">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-start w-100 bg-light px-3">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Please tell me how can I do it right?
Thanks in advance for any help!
I'm still learning and any help will go to good.

> This post has been completely changed, for a different task. The
> comments below are not relevant.

Comment: SO is not a code porting service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change below code with your navbar code.

```
<nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-lg-0 ">
  
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  
            <!-- Add logo with size of 90*80 -->
            <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/hqG.svg"  alt="">
        </a>

              </div>
```

Or replace the whole modified code in with your existing code

```css
.top-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
}

.top-line li {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <!-- CSS Bootstrap 4.5.2 -->

    <header>
        <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-lg-0 ">
  
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  
        <!-- Add logo with size of 90*80 -->
        <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/hqG.svg"  alt="">
    </a>

          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" >
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end top-line w-100 px-3">
             
              <li class="nav-   item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-start w-100 bg-light px-3">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Thank u so much. But it should be in the top left part of the navigation bar. That's the whole problem. Thank u very much again!

Comment: If it is possible, please tell me how it can be done.